# Cannot access a disposed object (System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream) on HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, dotnet-httpclient

**Updated 03/28/2017:**

This is a piece of C# code in my Xamarin PCL project running on iOS.

```
public async Task<string> uploadPhoto(string imageBase64)
{

      string responseContent = null;
      var uri = new Uri(Constants.uploadImageUrl);

      try
      {
           StringContent stringContent = new StringContent("photo=;base64," + imageBase64, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

           var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false); 

           // always check return success first
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
                responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
           }
           else
           {
                return null;
           }


           if (responseContent.Contains("Failed"))
           {
               return null;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(@"uploadPhoto        ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
           if (ex.InnerException != null)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(@"uploadPhoto        ERROR {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
           }
           return null;
       }

       return responseContent;
}
```

Exception thrown by client.PostAsync();

> [0:] Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

client.PostAsync() sometimes fails, it is not easy for me to replicate this exception.
I have no idea why PostAsync() would throw such exception. My internet connection was good, uri and content were validated.

Questions are:

1. Why PostAsync() throwing this exception when everything was good?
2. How System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream play it's role in this exception?

I hope someone out there can help answer these questions, and hopefully provide some guidance and light on solving this issue.

**Update:**

Here is the stack trace captured.
Exception thrown by client.PostAsync().

```
{System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x000d3] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:616 
  at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndWriteAsync>m__8 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs:729 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:1441 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00308] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:371 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <54e129cad3ee4c61a6b46c3680ddc69a>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.123/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <54e129cad3ee4c61a6b46c3680ddc69a>:0 
  at MyApp.RestService+<uploadPhoto>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00098] in D:\MyApp\MyApp\RestService.cs:147 }
```

Comment: Are you creating some objects in a using-block? For example the client?

Comment: Oh no, I did not use using keyword for the client.  My HttpClient was initialized in Constructor for my RestService class.

Comment: Turn out the exception was thrown by client.PostAsync(), the stack trace is up there. But why does PostAsync() throw such exception? I am scratching my hair off.

Comment: can you update your question and post your code? Otherwise it's difficult to help you. I think you dispose the client before your access it. Please post the first 4-5 rows from the stack trace as well.

Comment: The client was still there last time the exception was thrown. I will post my code later today.

Comment: There was a bug and maybe it is still there https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15066

Comment: FYI https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44502/objectdisposedexception-when-canceling-postasync

Comment: thanks, i've read those posts before,and I do think your're right they haven't fix the bug.

Comment: by the way i catched the exception and implemented a retry mechanism. Problem solved.

Comment: @CropP care to leave an answer?